# What are the image axes in php?

Tags: php

What are the axes for images in php? Do they start at the top left corner or bottom left? I can't seem to find this anywhere in the php.net documentation.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean in HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm drawing images in PHP (using the GD library), the axes start at the top left corner

X increases to the right and Y increases as you go down.

Is this what you meant?